# Android - how to know if user click on Home Screen

Tags: android, onclicklistener, homescreen

Is there a way to know if some user is clicked on the Home Screen of Android device. Something like `homeScreen.onclicklistener`

I tried to create a widgets and to listen for clicks, but this is not possible task, because there is no way to create widgets programmatically(auto adding), or maybe I don't know how to do it. I know this way is wrong but I had to tried.

Thanks in advance.

Screenshot from the Home Screen.

[image]

Comment: "Is there a way to know if some user is clicked on the Home Screen of Android device" -- write your own home screen, and then respond to touch events inside of that home screen's UI.

Comment: If you make that Home Screen app, please don't add widgets at the user click... In that case you'll give the worst UX possible!